# Integrating forums into site templates?

Tags: templates, forum

Ive read the EE documentation, and utilized other "solutions" for getting the forum to work at segment 2, but nothing seems to work - all result in a server error 500 page.

When set to default (forums) - works great.

When set to use template:  discussion/forum - and have the basic code in the template, nothing works.

EE - 2.6.1
Discussion Forum 3.1.12

HELP! - We need our forum to utilize EE modules!!!